# Pandas dataframe multiply entire column by single cell in another column controlling for group identifier

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am trying and failing to replicate a fairly simple excel formula in python. This is a screenshot of my dataframe and the caluclation in column F I am trying to perform:

[image: datafram]

Essentially for each 'activum' code I want to divide the cumprod value by its value in the year 1997 and then put the result of this in a new column in the dataframe.

In excel I would do this by locking the cell with the $ sign but given my dataframe is thousands of rows long and many combinations of activum and other group variables I am looking to code this in python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cumulative percentage for multi index dataframe in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057992/cumulative-percentage-for-multi-index-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) by new `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and filtered by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'statisticsjaar': [1995, 1996, 1997] * 2,
        'activum_statline':['A02'] * 3 + ['A04'] * 3,
        'cumprod':[7,8,9,4,2,3],

})

s = df[df['statisticsjaar'] == 1997].set_index('activum_statline')['cumprod']
print (s)
activum_statline
A02    9
A04    3
Name: cumprod, dtype: int64

df['new'] = df['cumprod'].div(df['activum_statline'].map(s))
print (df)
   statisticsjaar activum_statline  cumprod       new
0            1995              A02        7  0.777778
1            1996              A02        8  0.888889
2            1997              A02        9  1.000000
3            1995              A04        4  1.333333
4            1996              A04        2  0.666667
5            1997              A04        3  1.000000
```

If multiple columns need `join`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'statisticsjaar': [1995, 1996, 1997] * 2,
        'activum_statline':['A02'] * 3 + ['A04'] * 3,
        'cumprod':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
        'statlinebasiscode':['320700'] * 6,
        'niveau':['A38'] * 6,

})

cols = ['activum_statline','statlinebasiscode','niveau']
s = df[df['statisticsjaar'] == 1997].set_index(cols)['cumprod'].rename('new')
print (s)
activum_statline  statlinebasiscode  niveau
A02               320700             A38       9
A04               320700             A38       3
Name: new, dtype: int64

df['new'] = df['cumprod'].div(df.join(s, on=cols)['new'])
print (df)
   statisticsjaar activum_statline  cumprod statlinebasiscode niveau       new
0            1995              A02        7            320700    A38  0.777778
1            1996              A02        8            320700    A38  0.888889
2            1997              A02        9            320700    A38  1.000000
3            1995              A04        4            320700    A38  1.333333
4            1996              A04        2            320700    A38  0.666667
5            1997              A04        3            320700    A38  1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks. And for my own clarity how would the code change if I instead wanted to divide by 1996 instead of 1997 values?

Comment: @jyh5 - oops, my first solution was wrong. Check solution now, for `1996` change `df[df['statisticsjaar'] == 1997]` to `df[df['statisticsjaar'] == 1996]`

Comment: Thanks again. In my original df I have 3 variables which group the data (activumn_statline, statline_basiscode and niveau). The set index would then have three variables.  If I want to perform grouped calculations for all of these how would I expand the code?

Comment: @jyh5 - Added solution for it.

Comment: Sorry to come back again. But I am getting the following error message when running this line `s = df[df['statisticsjaar'] == 1997].set_index(cols)['cumprod'].rename('new')`. Error message Type error: 'str' object is not callable.

Comment: rename.(new) is the issue. The line of code works fine without that but if that is included an error message is returned.